# error sometimes occurs and sometime in different spots

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The below error pops up from time to time and not always at the same place.  Not exactly sure why.  Any clues?  Full code here : [Full Code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36ihfgEtWmRkhNpcP2yR8gw)

> File "/Users/davidkasapchuk/PycharmProjects/Test/HomeDepotFridges.py", line 257, in 
>       price = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 264, in find_element_by_class_name
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 478, in find_element
>       {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'product-display-price'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"138","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:52314","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1473895291967\", \"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"eb417d30-7ad1-11e6-82c2-d52d6cd5b804\", \"value\": \"product-display-price\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/eb417d30-7ad1-11e6-82c2-d52d6cd5b804/element/:wdc:1473895291967/element"}}
>   Screenshot: available via screen
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Test/HomeDepotFridges.py", line 266, in 
>       model = 'n/a'.text
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'>

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

b = open('csv/homedepotfridges.csv', 'w', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/appliances/refrigerators-and-freezers/refrigerators.html')
time.sleep(15)
items = []

for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item'):
    try:
        model = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-model')
        price = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
        title = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-title')
        url = item.find_element_by_class_name('js-detail-link')

        items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
        print (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        a.writerow(c)
   except NoSuchElementException:
    model = 'n/a'.text
    price = 'N/A'.text
    title = 'N/A'.text
    url = 'N/A'.text
    items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
    print(model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute.text("href"))
    c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
    a.writerow(c)
b.close()

b = open('csv/homedepotfridges.csv', 'a', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/appliances/refrigerators-and-freezers/refrigerators.html#!p=1&q=*%3Arelevance%3AcategoryPathHierarchy%3A3%2Fhd-classes%2Fl1-appliances%2Fl2-refrigerators-freezers%2F1010215')
time.sleep(15)
items = []

for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item'):
    try:
        model = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-model')
        price = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
        title = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-title')
        url = item.find_element_by_class_name('js-detail-link')

        items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
        print (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        a.writerow(c)
     except NoSuchElementException:
        model = 'n/a'.text
        price = 'N/A'.text
        title = 'N/A'.text
        url = 'N/A'.text
        items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
        print(model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute.text("href"))
        c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        a.writerow(c)
b.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use some kind of wait to wait for the elements to load before performing an action on them. That could solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't.  I have added a time.sleep(45), 45 second wait and still doesn't work.  It looks like the problem is with PhantomJS(), as when I do it with Chrome() and kill Chrome afterwards its all fine.

Comment: Maybe kill the chrome driver after the test runs in that instance? Shouldn't be keeping an instance of the chrome driver running if it's not needed anyway.